# Some results for the sequencewhere $a_{1} = 1$ and $a_{n + 1} = \sqrt{ 5+4a_{n} }$, for all $n ≥ 1$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Consider the sequence where $a_{1} = 1$ and $a_{n + 1} = \sqrt{ 5+4a_{n} }$, for all $n ≥ 1$.

- Show that $a_{n} ≤ 5$ for all $n$.
- Show that $a_{n}$ is increasing.

What Ive been thinking:

For the first one I use induction. Am I right?

For the second one I started doing this: I wore this and squared it both side: $a_{n + 1} > a_{n}$ -> $(\sqrt{5+4a_{n}})^{2} > (a_{n})^2$. Coming to a second degree inequality.

Comment: Induction for the first looks good, but you'll want to prove that $a\lt 5$ implies that $\sqrt{5+4a}\lt 5$ (which should be easy). Your approach for the second half looks fine; you know that $a_1=1$, so as long as you can prove that the inequality holds for $a$ in the range $[0,5]$ then you're good.

Comment: Actually it's $0 < a < 5$ (well, $-4/5 < a < 5$ would do but $0$ is simpler) that implies $\sqrt{5+4a} < 5$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fill in the blanks for the first one : note $a_1 =1\leq \_\_\_\_$ for the base step. Now for the induction step, if $a_n \leq \_\_\_\_\_\_$, then $ 5 + 4a_n \leq \_\_\_\_\_$, so the square root of this quantity is at most $\_\_\_\_\_\_\_$ i.e. $\sqrt{5 + 4a_n} = a_{n+1} \leq 5$.

For the second one : Squaring the expression you got gives you the inequality $a_n^2 -4a_n - 5 \leq 0$, which can easily be verified in the range $[0,5]$ either by completing the square or differentiating (once you notice that $a_n \geq 0$ for all $n$, of course).

These observations in fact show that $a_n$ is a convergent sequence. One uses the continuity of square root to deduce that the limit must be non-negative and satisfy $L = \sqrt{5+4L}$ by taking the limit in the recursion. Thus, $L= 5$ is the limit.

Comment: The first one is: $\leq 1$ the second blank: $ \leq 5$ the third $\leq 25$ and fourth:$\leq 5$. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 2):

First note that $a_1=1\geqslant 1$ and $x\mapsto\sqrt{5+x}$ is strictly increasing, so by induction $1\leqslant a_n < a_{n+1}$ and hence $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}>1$ for all $n$, so that $\{a_n\}$ is strictly increasing. Observe now that $a_1=1<5$, and assume that $a_n<5$ for some positive integer $n$. Then
$$
a_{n+1} = \sqrt{5 + 4a_n} < \sqrt{5+4\cdot 5} = \sqrt{25} = 5,
$$
so by induction it follows that $a_n<5$ for all $n$. Since $\{a_n\}$ is monotonically increasing and bounded above, $\sup_n a_n<\infty$, and $\sup_n a_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}$ exists. Now, taking the limit as $n\to\infty$ of the recurrence $a_{n+1} = \sqrt{5+4a_n}$ yields
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} a_{n+1} = \sqrt{5+4\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n} =\implies a = \sqrt{5+4a}.
$$
The solutions to this equation are $a=-1,a=5$. Since $a_n\geqslant1$ for all $n$, it follows that $a=5$.